# issue tracking sequence

Tags: tracking, movie-clip-editor

I am new to blender, I recently started to learn VFX.

I get an issue with tracking. I keep getting those 2 errors :
- `Failed to solve the motion: most likely there are no good keyframes`

And

```
At least 8 common tracks on both keyframes are needed for reconstruction
```

I tried with many different video sequences, tried manually add tracker, detect trackers automatically, I even tried with one sequences that had tons of trackers but still the same error.
Could you give me a hand?
[image]

Another image
[image]

This seems a lot of trackers but i tried it to see what was up, usually I only add like 20 trackers
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to cleanup your tracks with different error threshold from high to low. You have too many unnecessary tracking points. You need at least 8 good trackers, but having way too many might make the process less accurate. See: 
[How can I get better results when doing camera motion tracking?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking)

Then if Keyframe checked option won't work correctly, try to set the best key range!

Comment: how do you do that? And for info, I even went as far as selecting 2 keyframes next to each other (frame 1 and frame 2) and still got that error, is it a blender 2.81 error?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the solution.
See when I was adding a sequence, for some strange reason, it was not starting at frame 1, I mean I had to change the start frame to 250 and the frame offset to 1, so I think that messed things up, now I do not have that frame problem so all the track works well